# Getting redirected url PowerShell for webcrawler

Tags: powershell

I'm just recently starting to learn powershell and made a webcrawler. Im trying to get the redirected url to job listings.

```
$links=@();
For ($i=0; $i -lt 50; $i=$i+10)  {

   $arr=((Invoke-WebRequest –Uri (‘http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=software+engineer+entry+level+%2460%2C000&l=San+Diego%2C+CA&jt=fulltime&start=’+$i) -MaximumRedirection 2).Links
| Where data-tn-element -eq “jobTitle”).href;

 foreach ($arr in $arr) {

   $foo="https://www.indeed.com"+$arr -replace "mp;a","";

   $bar=Invoke-WebRequest –Uri ($foo) -MaximumRedirection 10;

   $test=$bar;
   #im trying to get the url of $bar
   $links+= $test;

 }
}
foreach($links in $links){

 echo $links;

}
```

With some editing i can get the links that indeed uses, but im trying to get the url where the actual job description is listed

Answer (score 1):

If you get a redirection, the result should be visible response of your invoke-webrequest object:

```
$bar.BaseResponse.ResponseUri
```

So:

```
$test = $bar.BaseResponse.ResponseUri
```